# Undeletable symbolic link on smbfs/simfs

Tags: filesystems, symlink

During a software installation, the `configure` script created a symbolic link with what seems to be `ln -s foo foo` on a `smbfs` filesystem mounted with the options

`credentials=/etc/fstab.passwd,uid=1001,gid=1001,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,rw`

The filesystem is `simfs` on the host machine. 
I tried to remove this symbolic link with `rm`, `unlink` but nothing works. 
The `stat` command cannot access any information. How could I remove this link ?

Comment: have you tried removing the symlink from the smbfs client?

Comment: Yes, I have tried.

Comment: It sounds as if the filesystem is confused because the symbolic link is pointing to itself.  You might try to see if you can rename the link, e.g., `mv foo foo2`.  If it lets you do *that*, then you might still have to create a dummy file named `foo` (by "touch foo") to appease the filesystem before removing the symbolic link ("rm foo2").

Comment: @ThomasDickey. Very clever ! It worked without any warning from the host machine (but failed from the remote). You should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: done - another detail which could be helpful in cases like this is that sometimes it helps to have the current working directory matching the link, so that no directory is given in the file operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if the filesystem is confused because the symbolic link is pointing to itself. You might try to see if you can rename the link, e.g., `mv foo foo2`. If it lets you do that, then you might still have to create a dummy file named foo (by "`touch foo`") to appease the filesystem before removing the symbolic link ("`rm foo2`").

Comment: Very clever ! It worked without any warning from the host machine (but failed from the remote). You should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try to delete this file by its inode:

```
ls -lasi | grep filename

find. -inum inode-number -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This does not work either.

Comment: How will that help? It's just going to run `rm -rf <filename>`.